# Ubuntu Server DNS Package Inspector

Tags: networking, server, dns

I'm looking to create a server that can track DNS queries to it. I have a domain name with Namecheap and for a project need to create a server that can log all incoming DNS queries. Is Ubuntu Server right for this? Can I set something up on my Ubuntu Server that can track and log queries such as this:

I have a domain name: domain.com
I have a program that should be able to send data like this: .domain.com

I need to be able to log . Is this possible with Ubuntu Server?

Comment: You should know that you won't be able to properly get useful query data, because of DNS Caching at other DNS servers (many systems don't actually directly query your DNS data, they query the DNS caching servers that their ISPs or Google or OpenDNS or others provide.  You won't be able to track that data for your domain name adequately because of that caching.  It's better to check site request and access logs to determine how many 'queries' you're getting.

Comment: @ThomasWard please see my answer and see if that works.

Comment: @heynnema I can't say whether it does or doesn't work until OP gives us more details about what exactly they're looking for, whether tracking remote queries for their own domains' DNS entries of whether they're looking for all the queries coming from their computer headed outbound.  There's not enough information to determine which answer is likely to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use opendns.com and opendns DNS servers...

`208.67.222.222`

`208.67.220.220`

Then you can use your "OpenDNS dashboard" to get (*showing clips*) reports like this:

[image]
and this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have to have 'stats and logs' turned on for that to work?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, in the settings panel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have or want install BIND9.

To permanently enable the log in BIND9 you should enable the following in the configuration:

**/etc/named.conf**

```
options {
querylog yes;
}

...
logging {
         channel querylog {
                 file "/var/log/querylog";
                 severity debug 3;
         };
};
```

Comment: This will work, but it won't help them if they are wanting to track requests for their domain *globally* and not just their own local queries.  They'd have to set up an authoritative nameserver with proper data, and update their DNS in the registrar to use that DNS server, and then realize they won't really see 'all' requests because of how DNS caching and resolution with DNS servers works.